# Autofac - Picking up implementation based on constructor' parameter name

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, autofac

Let's say I have such an interface:

```
interface IDateTimeProvider 
{
    DateTime GetNow();
}
```

And two implementations:

```
public class DateTimeProvider : IDateTimeProvider 
{
    public DateTime GetNow()
    {
        return DateTime.Now;
    }
}

public class DateTimeUtcProvider : IDateTimeProvider
{
    public DateTime GetNow()
    {
        return DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

I use Autofac to inject dependencies into my services. Some of my services require both implementations, some only one:

```
public class ServiceBoth
{
    (...)
    public ServiceBoth(IDateTimeProvider provider, IDateTimeProvider utcProvider)
    {
        (...)
    }
}

public class Service
{
    (...)
    public ServiceBoth(IDateTimeProvider provider)
    {
        (...)
    }
}

public class ServiceUtc
{
    (...)
    public ServiceBoth(IDateTimeProvider utcProvider)
    {
        (...)
    }
}
```

As you can see when I want to inject "DateTimeProvider" I call parameter with name "provider", but want to inject "DateTimeUtcProvider" I call parameter with name "utcProvider".

Now I'd like to use Autofac to implement such an dependency injection scenario:
1. I have two implementations of interface.
2. Which implementation is injected is determined by constructor's parameter name.
3. Everything should be implemented globally, I don't want create resolving mechanism for every service that uses IDateTimeProvider.

How?

Edit: As Steven noted in comment below, this approach violates Liskov Substitution Principle so I've decided to give up on this solution. But if anyone has any idea how to implement this "bad solution" - feel free to share.

Comment: Did you mean to give the method a name that does not implement the interface? `DateTime GetUtcNow()`

Comment: Nope, thank you for pointing this out. Fixed.

Comment: Did you read the docs and see [NamedParameter](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/parameters.html#available-parameter-types)?

Comment: Your design violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), since swapping those implementations will break the application. You should change your design. There are two options: 1 Merge both interfaces into one interface with two methods, or 2. Create two independent interfaces, e.g. `ITimeProvider` and `IUtcTimeProvider`.

Comment: @TravisIllig I would have to set for every services that uses my providers.

Comment: @Igor I didn't. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think, Autofac can't identify the parameter names, but you can define a second interface, which inherits from IDateTimeProvider and holds also GetNow()

```
public interface IDateTimeProvider
{
    DateTime GetNow();
}

public interface IDateTimeUtcProvider : IDateTimeProvider
{
}
```

Autofac can now resolve the correct service:

```
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<DateTimeProvider>().As<IDateTimeProvider>();
        builder.RegisterType<DateTimeUtcProvider>().As<IDateTimeUtcProvider>();
        builder.RegisterType<ServiceBoth>();
        builder.RegisterType<Service>();
        builder.RegisterType<UtcService>();
        var container = builder.Build();
        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var sb = scope.Resolve<ServiceBoth>();
            var s = scope.Resolve<Service>();
            var su = scope.Resolve<UtcService>();

            Console.WriteLine($"Both: {sb.Dt}, {sb.UtcDt}; Norm: {s.Dt}; Utc: {su.Dt}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Well, this problem comes down to the question: how to detect type of service during resolution. If I may only find out I could scan constructor with reflection and provide NameParameters with my custom algorithm.

Comment: Yes, if you are working with reflection, you need a ruleset for parameter naming.